# Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logical error

Tags: matlab

Q2. (30 points) The position d as a function of time (t) of a body that moves along a straight line is given by:

```
            d(t)= ‒ 0.2t4+0.5t3+15t-80 meters
```

The velocity v(t) of the particle is determined by the derivative of d(t) with respect to t, and the acceleration a(t) is determined by the derivative of v(t) with respect to t.
Derive the expressions for the velocity and acceleration of the particle by using your existing math knowledge, and make plots of the position, velocity, and the acceleration as a function of time for 0 ≤ t ≤ 10 s with 0.1 s increments similar to following screenshot. Use the subplot command to make the three plots on the same page with the plot of position on the top, the velocity in the middle, and the acceleration at the bottom. Label the axes appropriately with the correct units.

Could you help me for this question?

i wrote:

```
 t=1:0.1:10
```

then:

```
 d(t)=-0.2*t.^4+0.5*t.^3+15*t-80
```

but i says:

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

what does it mean?

Comment: In short: The 1.1 th element of `d` is and cannot be defined.

Comment: You are even telling us how many points this question will get you in your assignment. Classy...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error says, `t` needs to be an integer or logical.

But your t is `t=1:0.1:10`, therefore a decimal value.

you can just write (be aware that also `.*` is necessary)

`d = -0.2.*t.^4+0.5.*t.^3+15.*t-80`

and you will get a proper displacement vector `d` to your time vector `t`.

---

The reason is that you want to assign values to `d`, which requires indices, which are real positive integers. 
So you could, though not necessary, create an index vector:

```
idx_t = 1:numel(t);
```

and assign `d` like:

`d(idx_t) = -0.2.*t.^4+0.5.*t.^3+15.*t-80`

---

The second case, when the index vector is logical, it works like a mask.

e.g.

```
mask = logical( [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0] );
t_new = t(mask);
```

would delete every second value of your vector `t`.

Comment: He's cheating on a take home exam.  Here's your chance to earn the Disciplined badge.  :/

Comment: @chappjc hehe ;) well but the question was about the error message, he didn't asked for solving the plotting task. Though it's a funny copy&paste question, I think it's alright ;) It even motivated Dennis Jaheruddin to write a tutorial about this error.

Comment: Good point. It's still hilarious that he copied the question's point value!