# Why is this for loop giving me an error?

Tags: matlab

So I am trying to go through a for loop that will increment .1 every time and will do this until the another variable h is less than or equal to zero. Then I am suppose to graph this h variable along another variable x. The code that I wrote looks like this:

O = 20;

v = 200;

g = 32.2;

```
for t = 0:.1:12

   % Calculate the height

   h(t) = (v)*(t)*(sin(O))-(1/2)*(g)*(t^2);

   % Calculate the horizontal location

   x(t) = (v)*(t)*cos(O);

   if t > 0 && h <= 0
       break
   end
```

end

The Error that I keep getting when running this code says "Attempted to access h(0); index must be a positive integer or logical." I don't understand what exactly is going on in order for this to happen. So my question is why is this happening and is there a way I can solve it, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `t` as your loop variable as well as your indexing variable. This doesn't work, because you'll try to access h(0), h(0.1), h(0.2), etc, which doesn't make sense. As the error says, you can only access variables using integers. You could replace your code with the following:

```
t = 0:0.1:12;

for i = 1:length(t)
    % use t(i) instead of t now
end
```

I will also point out that you don't need to use a for loop to do this. MATLAB is optimised for acting on matrices (and vectors), and will in general run faster on vectorised functions rather than for loops. For instance, your equation for `h` could be replaced with the following:

```
O = 20;
v = 200;
g = 32.2;
t = 0:0.1:12;
h = v * t * sin(O) - 0.5 * g * t.^2;
```

The only difference is that you have to use the element-wise square (`.^2`) rather than the normal square (`^2`). This means that MATLAB will square each element of the vector `t`, rather than multiplying the vector `t` by itself.

Comment: Could I also use the vector for my equation for x,  like you said for the equation for h. And would using the vector for t make it possible to plot the points still? or would I still need to use a for loop to easily plot these points?

Comment: You can generate `x` in the same manner, and you should be able to plot them simply by calling `plot(t,x)` or `plot(t,h)`.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking one last question, I was wondering why in an example like,
 for i = 1:11;
    x(i) = (i-1)*(2*pi/10);
    ysin(i) = sin(x(i));
end;

I am able to use the (i), but I can not for my for loop. Would that be because in my for loop the numbers for t are decimals?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why. In the example you just gave, `i` is used to get data from the variable `x`. When `i==1`, you're saying you want the first element of the vector `x`, and so on. It doesn't make sense to ask MATLAB for the 'one-and-a-halfth' element of a vector, so you can only use integers for this process.

Answer (score -1):

In short:

As the error says, t needs to be an integer or logical.

But your t is t=0:0.1:12, therefore a decimal value.

```
O = 20;
v = 200;
g = 32.2;

for t = 0:.1:12

   % Calculate the height

   idx_t = 1:numel(t);

   h(idx_t) = (v)*(t)*(sin(O))-(1/2)*(g)*(t^2);

   % Calculate the horizontal location

   x(idx_t) = (v)*(t)*cos(O);

   if t > 0 && h <= 0
       break
   end
end
```

Look this question's answer for more options: [Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logical error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045549/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logical-error/20045631#20045631)

Comment: This won't work - you've replaced using a floating point value as an index with using a vector as an index every loop iteration.